# PowerShell crashes when using ref parameter in .NET event

Tags: .net, powershell, events, powershell-4.0

PowerShell crashes when an .NET-event with a `ref` parameter I've subscribed to, is invoked.

I've reduced the problem to the following code.

.NET:

```
namespace PSEventTest
{
    public delegate void BadHandler(ref string str);

    public class PSEventTest
    {
        public event BadHandler BadEvent;

        public void InvokeBad()
        {
            var handler = BadEvent;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                var str = "bad";
                handler(ref str);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PowerShell:

```
Add-Type -path $PSScriptRoot"\PSEventTest.dll"

$obj = New-Object PSEventTest.PSEventTest

$bad = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $obj -EventName BadEvent -Action {
    Write-Host "bad!" # it also crashes if this script-block is empty 
}

$obj.InvokeBad(); # crash
```

When i run the PowerShell script i get this:

[image]

If i press `Debug` i get this from Visual Studio:

[image]

The `copy exception detail to the clipboard` gives me this

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Unknown Module.
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I guess i have to provide the string to the `-Action` script-block somehow, but i don't know how.

P.S. I'm using PowerShell 4:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
4      0      -1     -1
```

Comment: I've been debugging some more. And i have found that the PowerShell script-block, is executed "out of sync" with the .NET code. If i make the same .NET code without the `ref`, what i see is that the event script-block is not executed before the call to `InvokeBad` terminates. Which means that in the case with the `ref` parameter, the .NET code execution is past the point where the reference can be updated once the PowerShell event script-block is executed.

This could be because I am invoking the event from PowerShell?

Comment: What does `$HOST.Runspace.ApartmentState` return? STA or MTA?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen `$HOST.Runspace.ApartmentState` returns `STA` both inside and outside of the event scriptblock.

Comment: There is no question in the question :) What would you like to know? Why PS crashes or how to solve the problem? Can you change the signature of the event or is it not your code?

Comment: Take a look at help for `Register-ObjectEvent`. It mentions `$Sender, $EventArgs`. Presumably, the cmdlet is designed to work with "standard" events with two parameters `(object sender, XyzEventArgs args)`. Try to change the event to "standard" and use your `XyzEventArgs` derived from `EventArgs` with needed members.

Comment: @RomanKuzmin My question is, how to keep PowerShell alive, and fire the scriptblock once the event is invoked. Sadly, I am not able to change the .NET code, it is legacy code that we are trying to integrate towards. I guess that PowerShell is simply not able to subscribe to such an event. I might be able to create a wrapper library that consumes the legacy code, and then forwards the event to PowerShell, the problem is that i need to change the `ref` in the legacy event-code, so i need to comunicate the result from the PowerShell scriptblock back to the legacy code somehow.

Comment: A wrapper library looks like a way to go then. Note that you do not have to create a DLL explicitly. You may create a helper class right in PS using `Add-Type @' C# class '@`. You may need to specify required `-ReferencedAssemblies` for this.

Comment: I reproduced this code and encounter a slightly different exception - an ExecutionEngineException which is a really low-level CLR exception that *really* shouldn't be occurring. There's no one hard-and-fast issue that causes it, but it *can* be tied to marshalling of parameters, and it sure seems that ref parameter is something the passing mechanism just isn't designed to handle.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the effort. I tried the wrapper library approach, but it is not solving the issue. The PowerShell event fires after the event in the wrapper library has finished executing, so I am not able to update the `ref` parameter. The only solution I see now, is writing all the integration logic directly in .NET where I can consume the event correctly. That's not a huge problem, but it means giving up the flexibility/simplicity provided by having a PowerShell script rather than a compiled assembly with a configuration file.

Comment: @JonList I've seen a few other posts where people have tried to write event procedures in Powershell declaring a ref parameter and the runtime kicked it out - "cannot use XXX& as a type argument" and I'm betting dollars to donuts that since the Powershell event  handler is created dynamically there's no good way to check for the ref argument at the "boundary" between the C# managed code and the Powershell runtime. Either that or it's simply an oversight in the PSEventHandler implementation or PS itself.

Comment: I guess i have to give Micorsoft a call next monday then :P

Comment: Have you tried adding the `-MessageData $someString` argument to Register-ObjectEvent ? That should be the data sent to the delegate

Comment: Yes i have. I could not get that to work either.

Comment: I tried the same thing - specifying the MessageData parameter - and it still crashes. I think the dynamic PSEvent object signature being created as the "proxy" back to the Action simply doesn't know how to handle a ref parameter properly, or if it tries, it does so incorrectly.

Comment: It'd definitely the `ref` causing the crash. If the `ref` is removed from BadEvent's signature, Powershell no longer crashes. The event even works also.

Comment: No idea if creating custom event accessors would help https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882534.aspx

Comment: @Eris Thanks! But I have already tried that. I added breakpoints in the accessors to see when the subscription from PS was added (and IF it was added). There are no surprises there, the subscription is added just fine, but invoking it still crashes PS. I think you are right about the `ref` parameter being the cause of the problem, unfortunately that is just how that code was written six years ago, and I can't really change it.

Comment: I just tried the accessor approach again, and this time, when standing in the breakpoint in the `add` body, i executed the handler using the "Immediate Window" in VS, and that gave me the same exception as @DavidW experienced; the `System.ExecutionEngineException`. I was not able to get a stacktrace, or any more usefull information though. I thought the HResult might help (0x80131506), but that just points back to the `System.ExecutionEngineException` exception.

Answer (score 6):

I found a **work-around** for this problem:

.NET:

```
namespace PSEventTest
{
    public delegate void BadHandler(ref string str);

    public class PSEventTest
    {
        public event BadHandler BadEvent;

        public string InvokeBad()
        {
            var handler = BadEvent;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                var str = "hi from .NET!";
                handler(ref str);
                return "from .NET: " + str;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    // as i mention below, this class can be implemented directly in the PS script
    public class BadEventSubscriber
    {
        public void Subscribe(PSEventTest legacyObj, Func<string, string> func)
        {
            legacyObj.BadEvent += delegate(ref string str)
            {
                var handler = func; 
                if (handler != null)
                {
                    var result = handler(str);
                    str = result;
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

PowerShell:

```
Add-Type -path $PSScriptRoot"\PSEventTest.dll"

$legacyObj = New-Object PSEventTest.PSEventTest
$subscriber = New-Object PSEventTest.BadEventSubscriber

$subscriber.Subscribe($legacyObj, {
    param([string]$str)
    write-host "from PS: $str"
    "hi from PS!" 
})

write-host $legacyObj.InvokeBad();
```

The result:

```
from PS: hi from .NET!
from .NET: hi from PS!
```

Previously I tried to create a `(object sender, EventArgs e)` type of handler to wrap the `(ref string str)` handler, but that did not work, because the PS event was fired out of sync with the .NET event.

Passing a `Func` in stead of using an event handler seems to work a lot better, as demonstrated in the code above.

I tried to generalize the `BadEventSubscriber` to use a `Expression<Func<object, handler>>` for selecting the event off of the passed object in the `Subscribe` method, but generics and `Delegate` don't play well together. So you would have to create a `BadEventSubsciber`-type class for every class and handler you would want to subscribe to (that PS does not "support"), but is it good enough for me at the moment.

<s>Its no real solution, as you would still need the additional assembly to "wrap" the event into a `Func`, but as a **work-around** i think it is okay.</s>

EDIT:

Now that i think about it, you can just define the subscriber class directly in PowerShell like @RomanKuzmin said in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30987362/powershell-crashes-when-using-ref-parameter-in-net-event?noredirect=1#comment50139714_30987362) to my original question. So instead of the additional assembly you just have the following in your PowerShell:

```
Add-Type @"
    using System;

    public class BadEventSubscriber
    {
        public void Subscribe(PSEventTest.PSEventTest legacyObj, Func<string, string> func)
        {
            legacyObj.BadEvent += delegate(ref string str)
            {
                var handler = func; 
                if (handler != null)
                {
                    var result = handler(str);
                    str = result;
                }
            };
        }
    }
"@ -ReferencedAssemblies $PSScriptRoot"\PSEventTest.dll"

$subscriber = New-Object BadEventSubscriber
```

Comment: This works for the simple case that i have posted, but "in the real world" I ran into problems with `Runspace` (the original event is fired from another thread or something like that). My PS script is already mostly workarounds for making the event with the `ref`-parameter work, so adding more workarounds to get the scriptblock to the right `Runspace` due to a `PSInvalidOperationException: There is no Runspace available to run scripts in this thread` exception, seems like too much work when i can just make a simple .NET app and make it work. Still, i learned stuff.